# System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following code in my controller that is saving the record to the db using EF.

```
[Route("api/abc/PostValues")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostValues(p_abc p_abc)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.p_abc.Add(p_abc);
        db.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, p_abc);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = p_abc.p_abc_id }));
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

The data gets written to the db fine.
But on the following line

```
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = p_abc.p_abc_id }));
```

I get following exception

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
  Source=System
  ParamName=uriString
  StackTrace:
       at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
       at App.Controllers.abcController.p_abc(p_abc p_abc) in c:\xxx\abcController.cs:line 127
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

Please let me know how to fix this exception

Comment: Can you verify that you have an entry in your `WebApiConfig.cs` for `DefaultApi`?  It should look something like: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created) responses, the Location is that of the new resource which was created by the request. For 3xx responses, the location SHOULD indicate the server's preferred URI for automatic redirection to the resource. The field value consists of a single absolute URI.

So you have to change your code as like this.
in route config.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default1",
        url: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Employees", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and in your post method

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage POSTEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Employees.Add(employee);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, employee);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("Default1", new { Id = employee.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no route to match the data.

Either your DefaultAPI route doesn't exist or it doesn't match the id you passed.
Hence the following code: `Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = p_abc.p_abc_id })` returns null;